# is there any common default function fpr APPmodel in cakephp.. which runs before the query execute

Tags: jquery, mysql, model-view-controller, cakephp-2.3

I wanted to add a query

```
$this->query('SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1'); // helps to run long queries
```

Is there any common function that runs before any function in appModel.
Like we have beforefilter function for controller that executes itself before executing any function.

So that I don't have to write the same code in each query and simply can define if in Appmodel.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to execute before any select queries, then i think u could use [beforeFind()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html). This function is called before any find-related queries.